# Progress dialog unnecessary showing

Tags: android

Hi i made an activity like

```
....
<TableRow >
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/userName"
        android:width ="100dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_userName"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:hint="@string/userName" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/password" />
</TableRow>
    ....
```

here is my class

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean rememberpassword = false;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        Button btn_logIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signIn );
        btn_logIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showProgressDialog();
                getUserCredentials();           
            }           
        }); //end of anonymous class
    } //end of onCreate

    private void showProgressDialog() {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait. Your authentication is in progress");
        dialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                
                dialog.dismiss();               
            }
        }); //end of anonymous class    
    } //end of showProgressDialog()

    private void getUserCredentials() {

        EditText txt_userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_userName);
        String userName = txt_userName.getText().toString();

        EditText txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        String password = txt_password.getText().toString();

        if (userName != null && !userName.trim().equals("") && password != null && !password.trim().equals("")) {           
            dialog.show();
            callWebServide(userName, password);         
        } else if (userName == null) {          
            Toast.makeText(this, "User Name is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
        } else if (password == null && password.trim().equals("")) {        
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
        }   
    } //end of getUserCredentials()

} //end of class LoginActivity
```

First my both conditions aren't working

```
} else if (userName == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "User Name is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
} else if (password == null && password.trim().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
}
```

Means when my activity launches then there is a hint in the editText, if i click on the login button then it should show toast that password or username is required. but it isn't :(. Second i used

```
if (userName != null && !userName.trim().equals("") && password != null && !password.trim().equals("")) {       
    dialog.show();
    callWebServide(userName, password);         
}
```

Means dialog should only be shown when userName and password must not be empty, but as soon as i click on login button then dialog start showing, only hints are in the editText. I didn't mention in my on click that `dialog.show()`. Although i am creating a dialog but aren't showing it.

why it is behaving unexpectedly? Am i doing anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you print out userName && password before the if block and see?

Comment: try with this check else if (userName == null || userName.lenght()==0) {   Toast.makeText(this, "User Name is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 0):

check should be

```
} else if (userName == null || userName.lenght()==0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "User Name is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
} else if (password == null || password.trim().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
}
```

for this

not sure about this one but test it once :

```
if ( (userName != null) && (!(userName.lenght()>0)) && (password != null) && (!(password .lenght()>0))) {       
    dialog.show();
    callWebServide(userName, password);         
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks :)  Yup it worked `else if (userName == null || userName.trim().equals(""))`. But can you tell me please what was going wrong when i was using `&&` instead of `||`. Also i changed a code little bit like `if (dialog == null) {dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);}`. Because i think using previous code whenever i clicked on the login button it was creating the new dialog instance, which is not good. What do you say about that, am i right?

Comment: let take (password == null && password.trim().equals("")) in this your password have to be null *and* blank "", both to move inside if , but it 'll not possible to be both null and "" for password at same time.......